# Creating a custom installation theme?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Usually i used to add a new project in visual studio to create a MSI,which provides a traditional design for installation and uninstall theme,but recently i saw an installation theme as in fig 2.

Fig 1 , creating a setup project :

[image]

Fig 2 , custom theme :

[image]
How could i add themes like those for my installations ?